# regex to match only 5 letter words

Tags: regex

I have an array and want to retrieve only 5 letter words, nothing longer, I have tried to use

```
$new = preg_grep("/.{5}/", $array);
```

but that resulted in any word that is at least 5 letters long.  I want any word that is at most 5 letters long.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the start (^) and end ($) modifiers, so

```
$new = preg_grep("/^.{5}$/", $array);
```

However, more efficient might be to just do a `strlen` based filter:

```
function len5($v){
   return strlen($v) == 5;
}
$new = array_filter($array, 'len5');
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the regex below to match words from 1 to 5 characters. `\b` is a word boundary

```
/\b\w{1,5}\b/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Do you want words that are *only* 5 letters long, or *at most* 5 letters long. Those are two separate things.

For the former:

```
$new = preg_grep("/^.{5}$/", $array);
```

For the latter:

```
$new = preg_grep("/^.{1,5}$/", $array);
```

The `^` and `$` anchors mark the beginning and end of the line respectively. If you didn't have markers, you would match a word like `abcdef` because `abcde` will match against your regular expression. You want to specify that you want to match against the entire string and not just the part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Add start (`^`) and end (`$`) markers:

```
$new = preg_grep("/^.{5}$/", $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

That will match in middle of a word as well. You need the word boundary switch I think it's `\w`

See this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html